# Converting csv to excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv, excel-interop

i am trying to convert a csv file to excel

i have this code

```
string targetFileName = GenerateTargetFileName(sourceFileName);
                string sourcePath = Path.Combine(sourceloc, sourceFileName);
                string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetloc, targetFileName);

               
                Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(sourcePath);
                Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                Excel.Range used = ws.UsedRange;
                used.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                wb.SaveAs(targetPath, 51);
                wb.Close();
                xl.Quit();

                //sylvan data way - file is corrupted and wont open - but saves
                //var csvreader = CsvDataReader.Create(sourcePath);
                //var excelwrite = ExcelDataWriter.Create(targetPath);
                //excelwrite.Write(csvreader);
```

it works fine on local machine but i need to run it on a server with no excel on - and i believe interop will not work on this so i am trying the

//sylvana data way - in code above - this generates a file but the file is smaller and corrupted each time and cannot be opened.

any suggestions how to get it to work on the server without excel

tried both ways above both generate a file - 1 works on local machine but does not work on server due to interop, the other way works on both but file is corrupted

Comment: You need to find library which reads CSV and library which can save excel's files without using excel itself ... Asking for library is off-topic (but for excel there is Open XML SDK from Microsoft which can write xlsx)

Answer (score 0):

With the Sylvan ExcelDataWriter you must dispose the writer. The finalization of the document happens during disposal, and without it you'll end up with a partially written file, as you're seeing.

I'm the author of that library, and yes the documentation is minimal, but I felt like this point was made pretty clearly in the example code:

```
// *critical* to dispose (using) ExcelDataWriter.
using var edw = ExcelDataWriter.Create("data.xlsx");
```